# Rails 4 simple_form field depending on submit button click

Tags: form-submit, simple-form, submit-button, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a simple_form with 2 submit button and depending on the button click, I would like to have one field :is_active to be true or false:

```
<%= f.button :submit, "active true", class: "regular", is_active: true %>
<%= f.button :submit, "active false", class: "regular", is_active: false %>
```

this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use two `submit_tag` in same form [check this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form) . Using params hash to check which button was clicked.

Please try like this:

```
<%= submit_tag 'active true', :name => 'active_true' %>
<%= submit_tag 'active false', :name => 'active_false' %>
```

In controller

```
if params[:active_true] 
   # do your stuff
elsif params[:active_false]
   # do your stuff
end
```